# Calculating torque from angular displacement (as a function of time)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics

I am an Engineering student studying for a physics exam later this month and came across this problem:

*It is given, that an angle to a point on a rotating wheel can be described using following function:*

$\theta(t)=3\; s^{-3}\cdot t^3 - 2\;s^{-2} \cdot t^2$

*At what time will the torque on the wheel be zero?*

Suggestions as to how I can solve this problem would be very much appreciated.

The answer is $t=2/9\; s$ btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall (in this case), that $\displaystyle \sum \tau = I\alpha$ and $\alpha = \dfrac{\mathrm d^2 \theta}{\mathrm d t^2}$.

Comment: Thanks man, that helped a lot. Have a nice day good sir

Answer (score 0):

Torque will result in angular acceleration. You have the formula for angle v. time, so you can use that to get angular velocity then angular acceleration v. time.